# Passing optional number of arguments into another function

Tags: php

Say I have a function called `addUp` which takes any number of decimal arguments and returns the result of them all added together.

If I have the following function:

```
function myTest(){
    $args = func_get_args();
    return addUp($args);
}
```

If I call `myTest(1,2,3)` obviously this will not work as I'm only passing one argument to `addUp` and that is an array.

Is there a way to pass all the arguments passed into `myTest` on into the `addUp` function (without editing the `addUp` function)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

It calls a function with the arguments derived from an array (which is what you get from `func_get_args()`).

Answer (score -1):

You can pass in an array and then iterate through it.

```
$args = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

function myTest($arr){
    $r = 0;
    foreach($arr as $value){
        $r += intval($value);
    }

    return $r;
}

echo myTest($args);
```